# Drop of accuracy when using tf.keras.utils.Sequence as data generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am training an image classifier with 2 classes using ResNet50. I want to use the `keras.utils.sequence` to create a data generator. I have followed the tensorflow example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence).

**My problem** : When I directly load the data (without generator) and then train my model, I get a good accuracy (around 0.98). When I am using the data generator the accuracy drop to 0.70.

I have done some tests to understand where this dropping come from.

**My tests** :

- I checked my data using the `__getitem__` of my generator -> everything is ok.
- I loaded all my data before training using the generator and then trained my model using this data(with the same batch number) -> I get a good accuracy.
- I checked that the model.fit() method recognize the keras.utils.sequence generator.

So, I concluded that my problem came from the "inside" of model.fit() when using the generator? I saw that keras.utils.sequence is commonly used, and I didn’t find similar issues.

Can anyone see where my problem comes from or have some ideas of other test I could run?

**My code** :

Data generator :

```
from math import ceil
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence


class DataGeneratorSV(Sequence):
    """
    Generates data.
    """

    def __init__(
        self, x_set, y_set, batch_size=32, size=128, channels=3
    ):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.size = size
        self.channels = channels

    def __len__(self):
        return ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        return np.array(
            [
                cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(file_name),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), (self.size, self.size))
                for file_name in batch_x
            ]
        ), np.array(batch_y)
```

Model:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input

from .generate_data import DataGeneratorSV
  

# X : path to images
[...]

train_generator = DataGeneratorSV(X_train, labels_train, batch_size=32, size=128, channels=3)
val_generator = DataGeneratorSV(X_val, labels_val, batch_size=32, size=128, channels=3)

ResNet50(weights="imagenet",
         include_top=False,
         input_shape=(128,128,3),
         pooling="avg",
         )
ResNet50.trainable = False

dropout = 0.5
classes = 2
head_neural_net = [
    layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dropout(dropout),
    layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dropout(dropout),
    layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dropout(dropout),
    layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(classes),
]

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Lambda(preprocess_input, input_shape=[128,128,3]))
model.add(ResNet50)
for layer in head_neural_net:
    model.add(layer)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=10
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    validation_data = val_generator,
   epochs=epochs
 )
```

Python 3.8.13 and tensorflow 2.7.1

Comment: Is it possible that you're not shuffling your data?

Comment: The data are shuffled (I have the 2 classes represented in one batch)

Comment: @Adhx what he is saying, is that, are you sure that `y_train` are not all zeros and then all ones?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes, I am sure that y_train are not all zeros and then all ones.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and the issue ended up being my `batch_y` was like `[[1], [0], [3], [2], ...]` while with `loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`, I think it's expected to be like `[1, 0, 3, 2, ...]`